# wordpress / genesis refresh issue sidebar

Tags: wordpress, caching, browser-cache, genesis

I have a problem that my visitors don't see the latest version of my Wordpress website. The website i'am speaking about is [www.kndb.nl](http://www.kndb.nl). When a new newsitem is published, the newsitem will be displayed in the sidebar on the right side.

Visitors are complaining that they don't see the latest published newsitems, sometimes it takes one or two days when they see the latest version. The same problem occurs when you visit the website on a tablet. You have to to (multiple) refresh to see the latest version.

It is remarkable when you click on the logo, that the elements on the left side of the page refreshes, but the sidebar not.

To display the newsitems on the sidebar i use the plugin: "Genesis Featured Widget Amplified". I have checked the code, and there is no caching used.

Hereby some extra info.

- hosting: siteground
- wordpress: 4.3
- theme: custom genesis theme
- dynamic cache: off
- memcache: off

Hopefully somebody can help me with this issue, i have already spend a lot of time and have no clue. Furthermore i want to enable the dynamic-caching and memcache again, because i think the current problem has nothing to do with these settings.

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

It should not happen as you have all caches off and also I see the view-source and see no trace of any cache. You said you are using Amplified Plugin, in their comments I read, that is uses transient API to speed up work, it is type of cache also.

> WP_Query optimization for speed including site transients and term
>   cache updating ~ from the plugin page here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/genesis-featured-content-widget/

To clear transient cache you might need to delete object cache. You may look into this and see why your transient cache is not being updated when posting new posts. You may contact Siteground support for any server level caching or explore more about the plugin's caching behavior, sorry cannot give exact solution at this time as have not faced this issue myself.

Good luck!